# Hash two addresses in vyper

Tags: hash, vyper

I'm trying to write a function in vyper that takes two addresses and returns a 256-bit hash (either keccak256 or sha256).

Afaik the builtin hash functions only take `Bytes`, `bytes32` and `Strings` as inputs, and there are no [type conversions](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#type-conversions) from `address` to any of those types.

How can I make a hash of two addresses like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, with slightly different results.

```
# @version 0.3.2

# address1 and address2 are left-padded with zeros before the hash
keccak256(_abi_encode(address1, address2))

# bytes20 is available as of v0.3.2
# hash the 40 bytes of the two addresses concatenated together
keccak256(concat(convert(address1, bytes20), convert(address2, bytes20))
```